# Metadata Reject : The rating you’ve selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app

Tags: ios, iphone, metadata, appstore-approval, rating

I have just update a some small feature in my new version of app and Apple has rejected my app for asking demo account details and Why is the user required to register with his phone number?, after providing required information they again rejected my app with following reason.

**The rating you’ve selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app.**

Now how should i decide rating of my app as it doesn't contain any such thing as described in [App Rating Detail](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/views/shared/app_store_rating_matrix.html) page through which it should not come in 4+ rating.

My app is all about collecting funds for social causes through some physical competition/events between participant teams.

My app is also reviewed 12 times already through on appstore. I viewed the Review Guidelines, and looked at the metadata, and I still have no idea which part should I change. So please suggest me what what should i do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because AppStore-approval is off topic for stack overflow. You need to work with Apple to ask them what rating would be applicable. As you are collecting personal information it probably needs to be at least 13+ in the US but it could also be that reviewer at Apple is confusing rating with your need for a privacy policy

Answer (score 0):

What have you used for collecting funds in your app? Is it IAP?

For rating error,could you describe more about your app?

Also, I guess as your app collects funds for social causes **through some physical competition/events between participant teams**, you might need to select the last option while you select ratings in iTunes.

[image: See the screenshot of iTunes rating options]